# Running cells with 'Python 3.9.5 64-bit' requires ipykernel installed or requires an update

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I am getting error `Running cells with 'Python 3.9.5 64-bit' requires ipykernel installed or requires an update.` in visual studio code if I switch anywhere else from `home` directory. 
For example everything is ok when i run this file from home directory
[image]

And the same file gives error when I open `auto_script` folder
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the bottom left corners of pictures. In the first one, you're using conda environment but in the second one default system python selected. You should activate or select your conda environment or install ipytkernel to system default.